# R conditional loop to replace vallues

Tags: r, loops, replace, conditional-statements, mean

I am looking to conditionally replace values in a column and I think a loop is what I need. Though I know on a basic level how loops work, I have little experience using them so I struggle with wrapping my head around the order of operations. Using the dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(player = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", 
"p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", 
"p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", 
"p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", "p1", "p2", "p3", 
"p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", "p1", "p2", 
"p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", "p1", 
"p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11"), 
    Date = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3"), `Period Number` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `IMA High Total` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 43L, 51L, 13L, 84L, 74L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 40L, 
    75L, 2L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 26L, 9L, 0L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 
    48L, 53L, 9L, 51L, 53L, 3L, 23L, 21L, 68L, 56L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
    9L, 15L, 9L, 0L, 15L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 1L), Dur = c(67.6, 98.3, 
    50.5, 93.3, 97.5, 51, 42, 61.8, 94.7, 107.2, 42, 41.9, 41.9, 
    41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 62.5, 
    90.4, 44.5, 88.9, 87.3, 48.3, 40.2, 55.4, 84.5, 94.5, 40.2, 
    39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 39.1, 
    39.1, 75.4, 87.9, 42.2, 90.2, 86, 47.5, 49.8, 60.1, 104.3, 
    108.1, 42.2, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 
    42.1, 42.1, 42.1)), row.names = c(727L, 728L, 729L, 730L, 
731L, 732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 740L, 741L, 
742L, 743L, 744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 793L, 794L, 795L, 796L, 
797L, 798L, 799L, 800L, 801L, 802L, 803L, 804L, 805L, 806L, 807L, 
808L, 809L, 810L, 811L, 812L, 813L, 814L, 859L, 860L, 861L, 862L, 
863L, 864L, 865L, 866L, 867L, 868L, 869L, 870L, 871L, 872L, 873L, 
874L, 875L, 876L, 877L, 878L, 879L, 880L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to replace the 0 values in column "IMA High Total" for D1, with the means from D2 and D3 with the conditions of "player" column and "period number" column when Dur > 1. An subset example would look like turning this

```
     player Date Period Number IMA High Total  Dur
727     p1   D1             0              0 67.6
738     p1   D1             1              0 41.9
793     p1   D2             0             43 62.5
804     p1   D2             1             12 39.1
859     p1   D3             0             48 75.4
870     p1   D3             1              7 42.1
```

into this

```
     player Date Period Number IMA High Total  Dur
727     p1   D1             0             46 67.6
738     p1   D1             1             10 41.9
793     p1   D2             0             43 62.5
804     p1   D2             1             12 39.1
859     p1   D3             0             48 75.4
870     p1   D3             1              7 42.1
```

If there is an easier way than loop, than great! Thanks for help, the stackoverflow community has been very helpful with my R learnings.

Comment: Could you add an example of how the expected output should look? I don't really understand what the "conditions" in your description should do?

Comment: Another question: if `Dur <= 1`should the solution just ignore the case?

Comment: An example of expected output is added. Additionally if Dur <=1 the case can be ignored. That would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `player` and `Period Number` and ``` replace ``IMA High Total ``` where `Date = "D1"` and `IMA High Total = 0` with `mean` of value where `Date` is not `"D1"` and `Dur > 1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(player, `Period Number`) %>%
  mutate(`IMA High Total` = replace(`IMA High Total`, Date == "D1" & 
                                     `IMA High Total` == 0, 
                            mean(`IMA High Total`[Date != "D1" & Dur > 1]))) %>%
   arrange(player, `Period Number`)


#   player Date  `Period Number` `IMA High Total`   Dur
#   <chr>  <chr>           <int>            <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 p1     D1                  0             45.5  67.6
# 2 p1     D2                  0             43    62.5
# 3 p1     D3                  0             48    75.4
# 4 p1     D1                  1              9.5  41.9
# 5 p1     D2                  1             12    39.1
# 6 p1     D3                  1              7    42.1
# 7 p10    D1                  0             65.5 107. 
# 8 p10    D2                  0             75    94.5
# 9 p10    D3                  0             56   108. 
#10 p10    D1                  1              9    41.9
# … with 56 more rows
```

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks for help!